# test_re failed while installing Python 3.5.2 in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, ubuntu-14.04, python-3.5

I want to install Python 3.5.2 along with 2.7 on my Ubuntu 14.04. When I was testing using `make test`, it gave the following error for `test_re`.

```
FAIL: test_locale_flag (__main__.ReTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Lib/test/test_re.py", line 1349, in test_locale_flag
    self.assertTrue(pat.match(bletter))
AssertionError: None is not true

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 114 tests in 0.874s
```

I tried searching the internet but to no avail.
Any help would be appreciated.